# Aframe-animation-component animations not firing twice

Tags: aframe

I have a few animations being fired from a `mouseenter` event. Works just fine the first time around and then when I attempt to fire the animation again it gets to the `beginAnimation` function on the `aframe-animation-component`, which means it should emitting the `animationbegin` event but at that point nothing happens and the `complete` function in the config object never ends up running like it does when the animation runs fine the first time. Trying to figure out what parts I should be looking at to debug this but I'm having a hard time. Thanks! Also, I'm using the newest version off of kframe repo.

Comment: Could you share some code snippet?

Comment: Currently working on this now. This is more of an issue than a question. But will have it fixed at some point.